# SQL to get only the mismatches columns

Tags: sql, oracle, testing, etl

I wanted to know if we can get only the mismatched dataset from a table while doing volume testing please look at the below example:

If the below table is my target table which I perform my testing if the data is correctly loaded, I would write a SQL to select the columns from source and do a minus to the target table, if let's say the source has `sal` of XXX as 2000 then that's a mismatch from source to target, is it possible to get only id and sal column as output from the minus query.

To be clear if I have a table with 100 columns to do testing the minus query would return all the 100 columns even if there is a mismatch in 1 column so I want only 1 column to be returned which has the mismatch.

```
id  Name sal
--  ---- ----
1   XXX 1000
2   YYY 2000
3   ZZZ 4000
4   AAA 5000
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: what have you tried yourself? Hi and welcome to SO. Please add essential parts of your code/query. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its in oracle

Comment: @davejal thanks, yes this is the first time. the query is too long to post so I just explained the scenario. I am validating a table from Test environment (tedw) to Prod environment(pedw).. so the table has 100 columns and need to find the mismatched columns, I am validating it with a minus query but it results in all the columns even if there is mismatch in one column and more over i have to manually check which column has the mismatch from the minus query result... so I want to avoid this and get only the mismatched columns as my result set.

Comment: @harikamireddi did you find a useful way to do this

Answer (score 2):

With the assumptions below

Both the source and target tables have a common primary Key

Then the a case statement can be used to narrow down on the exact column which is causing the mismatch

[http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a78eca/16](http://SQL%20Fiddle%20Link)

```
select 
ST.id,
case 
when ST.name!=TT.name then 'Issue in name' 
When ST.sal!=TT.sal then 'Issue in Sal'
Else 'OK' END As Check_Column
From source_table ST, Target_table TT
where ST.id=TT.id
and (ST.name!=TT.name OR ST.sal!=TT.sal)
```

The explanation for above is that the where condition will filter out only the offending rows and the case statement will tell which row is causing the mismatch

Comment: Hi sid thanks for the response,  but as I said there are 80 columns in the table that need to be compared is it really feasible with case statement

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your target data set is in 'TargetTable' and your source data set is in 'SourceTable'; Perhaps you could try something like:

```
SELECT Name, Sal FROM TargetTable as t
WHERE (NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT Name, Sal from SourceTable as s
     WHERE(Name = t.Name) OR (Sal = t.Sal)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following assumptions:

1. You are only comparing the sal columns for the source and target
2. Source and target are joined based on the id primary key

The query could be written as:

```
SELECT
        T1.Name, T1.sal, S1.sal
FROM
        schemaName.TargetTable T1, 
        schemaName.SourceTable S1
WHERE 
        T1.id = S1.id
        AND T1.sal <> S1.sal
```

Comment: I had a typo in my select statement. Changed T2.sal to S1.sal